# does AndParcel allow android Library projects?

Tags: android

Well, I might as well post the fist question.

Does AndParcel allow Android Library project functionality? Meaning, I should be able to include an Android Library project as a parcel correct or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not attempted to use Android library projects, and therefore I cannot state whether or not it works.

IMHO, the two technologies are orthogonal. An Android library project would be used for internal development; a parcel would be used for wider distribution. It is conceivable that there is a reason to distribute an Android library project beyond a single team, but I have no idea what that reason would be, and I have no idea if parcels would be the appropriate means of distribution, compared to publishing your own Maven repo or something.

Further questions regarding the Android Parcel Project probably should go to the [cw-android Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android).

Comment: Note, I found that I can distribute android library projects for others to use if I include the proper ant script..however not as feature rich as your solution